# Do you have to have command line access to use Subversion with Wordpress?

Tags: svn, command-line

My group does not have command line access to the machine that is running our WordPress instance. However, we would still like to install/update using Subversion. Is this possible? Also, does Subversion need to be on the same machine?

Comment: The reason I ask is because that is the first line on this page --> http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing/Updating_WordPress_with_Subversion

Comment: I would assume that you do, considering it begins with "If you have command-line access...". Are you just concerned about easily upgrading WordPress in the future?

Comment: I am tempted to close this as offtopic, since the question is pretty much about Subversion. You might get better answer for such on other sites in SE network.

Comment: My question is specifically about WordPress and how you implement it with Subversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to have subversion installed on the same machine and command line access to the machine.

Comment: could you explain why? Thanks!

Comment: In order to follow the WP codex directions for installing/upgrading via SVN, you must have it on the same server. I suppose if you have access to another server where you could checkout WP core via SVN, and then your IT dept would allow an rsync between that SVN checkout and the web server, you may be able to get it to work. But if you can't get shell access, I doubt you would be able to setup an rsync for the files. Can the IT department configure SVN and be responsible for running the upgrade? As in you file a ticket with them, and they run the `svn sw` command when it's time to upgrade?